# Проблема с ADOTable

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 list1:=ADOTable1.FieldByName('login').AsString;
 label3.Caption:=list1;
 list2:=ADOTable1.FieldByName('password').AsString;
 label4.Caption:=list2;
 If edit2.Text=list2 Then label5.Caption:='0'
 else label5.Caption:='1';
end;
```

Условие всегда неверно (label5 выводит 1), хотя в edit2 вводится верный пароль. Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что это заморочки с `varchar`-ами и `ADOTable1.FieldByName('password').AsString` возвращает, допустим, не `"pass"`, а `"pass     "`. Т.е. там в хвосте поля плетется охапка пробелов в результатах запросов.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.

Comment: Если помогло, отметьте ответ как принятый.